# Tag synonym: short-story / short-stories

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) has a wiki entry and more questions, but making the singular [short-story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story) makes a bit more sense to me, so I really don't care which way the synonym goes, but we should have one one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. I made [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) the master tag because it had more uses, and it had a tag wiki, and the general trend across Stack Exchange is to use plurals.